# How to override ERC20 _beforeTokenTransfer and _afterTokenTransfer functions if there is no need of this in my contract

Tags: erc-20, abstract, function-override, virtual

I am trying to use openzepplin's ERC20 token and because of this two functions _beforeTokenTrandfer and _afterTokenTransfer I has to use abstract in my smart contract and because of abstract its not deploying.
So How do I override this functions without using abstract?
This is my contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

abstract contract BankOfPeople is ERC20 {

    uint256 private lendingPool = 0;
    address private immutable i_owner;

    struct Account {
        string accountHolderName;
        address accountAddress;
        uint accountBalance;
        uint amountBorrowed;
        uint shareInPool;
    }

    Account[] public accounts;

    mapping(address => uint) addressToBalance;
    mapping(address => Account) addressToAccount;
    mapping(uint => uint) idToBalance;
    mapping(address => uint) addressToId;

    string private s_name;
    string private s_symbol;

    constructor(
        string memory name_,
        string memory symbol_,
        address owner_
    ) {
        s_name = name_;
        s_symbol = symbol_;
        i_owner = owner_;
    }

    function _createAccount(string memory _name) public {
        accounts.push(Account(_name, msg.sender, 0, 0, 0));
        uint id = accounts.length - 1;
        idToBalance[id] = 0;
        addressToId[msg.sender] = id;
    }

    function _depositMoney(address _address) public payable {
        uint id = addressToId[_address];
        accounts[id].accountBalance += msg.value;
        lendingPool += msg.value;
        accounts[id].shareInPool = accounts[id].accountBalance / lendingPool;
    }

    function _withdrawMoney(uint _amountToWithdraw) public {
        uint id = addressToId[msg.sender];
        require(
            _amountToWithdraw <
                (accounts[id].accountBalance - _lockedETH(msg.sender))
        );
        accounts[id].accountBalance -= _amountToWithdraw;
        payable(accounts[id].accountAddress).call{value: _amountToWithdraw};
        lendingPool -= _amountToWithdraw;
        accounts[id].shareInPool = accounts[id].accountBalance / lendingPool;
    }

    function _viewBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        uint id = addressToId[msg.sender];
        return accounts[id].accountBalance;
    }

    function _borrowMoney(uint _amountLent) public {
        uint id = addressToId[msg.sender];
        require(
            _amountLent <
                (2 * (accounts[id].accountBalance - _lockedETH(msg.sender))) / 3
        );
        _mint(msg.sender, _amountLent);
        accounts[id].amountBorrowed += _amountLent;
    }

    function _repayMoney(uint _amountRepaid) public payable {
        uint interest = _amountRepaid / 10;
        require(msg.value == interest);
        uint id = addressToId[msg.sender];
        _burn(msg.sender, _amountRepaid);
        accounts[id].amountBorrowed -= _amountRepaid;
        _payInterest(interest);
    }

    function _lockedETH(address _address) internal view returns (uint) {
        uint id = addressToId[_address];
        return (3 * (accounts[id].amountBorrowed)) / 2;
    }

    function _payInterest(uint _interest) internal view {
        payable(i_owner).call{value: _interest / 2};
        for (uint id = 0; id < accounts.length; id++) {
            payable(accounts[id].accountAddress).call{
                value: accounts[id].shareInPool * (_interest / 2)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it is abstract because the `ERC20` constructor isn't called.

The call to the constructor should look like this:

```
contract BankOfPeople is ERC20 { /// <---- Remove abstract

    // ...

    constructor(
        string memory name_,
        string memory symbol_,
        address owner_
    ) ERC20(name_, symbol_) { /// <---- Add ERC20 constructor
        i_owner = owner_;
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: Why do we call the constructor of ERC20? Do we call constructor in every contract in which we use ERC20 token? And after calling constructor of ERC20 token why we do not need this body less functions _beforeTokenTransfer and _afterTokenTransfer?

Comment: @Aman You need to call ERC20's constructor because it requires two parameters. For a contract to be deployable you need to call the base contracts' constructor. You shouldn't need to override `_beforeTokenTransfer` & `_afterTokenTransfer` in recent versions they are implemented with an empty body, see https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L364-L368.

Answer (score 0):

Call the inherited method with the super keyword. Example for `_beforeTokenTransfer`:

```
function _beforeTokenTransfer(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 amount
) internal virtual override {
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
}
```

Comment: I have used super in both the functions and compiled it on remix IDE but then also it is throwing error to use abstract in contract.